# luarocks install local source

Tags: lua, torch, luarocks

I am making edits to a file in the nn Library.  It has a rockspec file.  When I luarocks install that rockspec file, it downloads the git source. I want it to use my local source.  The rockspec file has all sorts of compile time command line gibberish that I don't want to invoke manually. Something like `$ luarocks install nn.rockspec --source='~/nn'` would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For local source, you need to go into the directory and issue:

```
luarocks make rocks/nn-scm-1.rockspec
```